# Clojure: Defining a symbol in another namespace

Tags: clojure

### Context

This is the contents of init.clj

```
(ns init)

(defn get-hotswap []
  (filter #(= (ns-name %) 'hotswap) (all-ns)))

(let [x (get-hotswap)]
  (let [old-ns *ns*]
    (if (empty? x)
      (do
        (create-ns 'hotswap)
        (in-ns 'hotswap)
        (def global-kv-store (clojure.core/atom {}))
        (in-ns (ns-name old-ns)))
      (println "Found Hotswap"))))
```

Now. hotswap/global-kv-store does not exist, but init/global-kv-store does exist.

### Question

How do I fix this? I want to be able to

- create a new namespace hotswap
- and then define a new variable global-kv-store in it

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
(if-not (find-ns 'hotswap)
  (intern (create-ns 'hotswap) 'global-kv-store (atom {})))
```

Comment: intern, not in-ns/def, is what I wanted. Thanks! BTW, purely for sake of learning, can you explain why in-ns/def does not work? Intutiively, I switch to the 'hotswap namespace, then I define something in it ... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @user1311390 I'm not sure. I think the problem is, that the value of `*ns*` that is taken is the one from compile time (which is the init namespace), not from runtime. Again, don't take this as a definitive answer, as it may be totally wrong.